# ORA-01031 in insert

Tags: insert, ora-01031

i was running an insert query on a synonym i got ORA-01031 in sql developer, we are accessing almost all tables through synonym only, but only this one in the schema gave ORA-0103 error. Please guide.

```
Error report: SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to change the current username or password
           without the appropriate privilege. This error also occurs if
           attempting to install a database without the necessary operating
           system privileges.
           When Trusted Oracle is configure in DBMS MAC, this error may occur
           if the user was granted the necessary privilege at a higher label
           than the current login.
*Action:   Ask the database administrator to perform the operation or grant
           the required privileges.
           For Trusted Oracle users getting this error although granted the
           the appropriate privilege at a higher label, ask the database
           administrator to regrant the privilege at the appropriate label.
```

Answer (score 3):

did you execute something like:

```
GRANT select, insert, update, delete on Table to your_synonym_user;
```

and this line should be executed by the Table owner or the user with that permission.

Comment: I had the same problem with that and I forgot to grant insert any table permission to my user.

Answer (score 0):

It looks very much like the permissions you have to either the underlying table, or the synonym are insufficient, or possibly that your password has expired?